# Pulling SQL data into an ASP.net web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I tried searching for this, but I can't find an answer that works.   All I need to do is find a way to display SQL data from a simple query onto an aspx page.  I'm using C# to connect to the database.  I have not trouble posting to the database.  My code seems correct.  I'm not getting any errors, however, the web page doesn't display anything.

**Here is the code on the C# file**:

```
public int GetResults( )
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data"].ConnectionString); 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count (ColumnA) from TableA",conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    conn.Open();
    int Rslt= (Int32)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return (Rslt);
}
```

**And here is the aspx page:**

```
<div class="lc">      
  the results are=  <%GetResults();%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ExecuteScalar()` rather like

```
int Rslt= (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Again, the calling doesn't looks correct. It rather should be

```
<%# GetResults() %>
```

As @Jacob pointed: `<% %>` is for executing a code block; whereas `<%= %>` or `<%# %>` is for outputting content.

Comment: To explain the last part, `<% %>` is for executing a code block; `<%= %>` or `<%# %>` is for outputting content.

Comment: But I'd use `<%: GetResults() %>` to automatically HTML-encode the output.

Comment: Thank you, Jacob!    The <%: GetResults() %>   worked.